# Array not rerendering

Tags: lightning-web-components, rerender, array

I can't get my array to rerender my lightning component. The boolean value rerenders fine. I've tried setting the data by direct assignment, using the spread syntax and as below, using map. What am I missing?

```js
export default class MyFirstWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track companies = [];
    @track isLoaded = false;


    connectedCallback() {
        this.init();
    }

    async init() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("https://example.com/api/salesforce/companies");
            console.log('json', await response.json()) // this console logs fine

            this.isLoaded = true;

            const data = await response.json();
            this.companies = data.map(val => ({ label: val.label, value: val.value }))
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("There's a problem with your fetch operation:", error);
        }
      }
```

```html
         <lightning-combobox
            name="company"
            label="Account"
            value={value}
            options={companies}
         </lightning-combobox>
         foo: {companies} <- this is empty
         <br>
         isLoaded: {isLoaded} <- this outputs true
```

Comment: Please check that the in js data variable has a value. Add a console log for the data variable and check.

Comment: ```const response = await fetch("https://example.com/api/salesforce/companies");
const data = await response.json();
console.log('json', data) // this console logs fine

this.isLoaded = true;
this.companies = data.map(val => ({ label: val.label, value: val.value }))
```

Comment: @TusharJadav Oh snap. It must have been because I called `await response.json()` twice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the data twice (in the console log and in the assignment to `data`), store it somewhere and use it twice:

```js
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/api/salesforce/companies");
const data = await response.json();

console.log('json', data);

this.isLoaded = true;
this.companies = data.map(val => ({ label: val.label, value: val.value }));
```

The reason is that you can call `.json()` just once. If you call it twice, like in your snippet, you'll get an "Body has already been consumed." error on the second call. In your case, you are consuming the body when logging it to the console, and trying to call it again after. And your snippet is catching the error in the try/catch block too.

In my snippet, you call `.json()` just once and use the contents of `data` instead.